# How to add zeros to 2d slice string elements

Tags: string, algorithm, go, slice

The task is to add zeros to string elements of 2d slice. So the stdin is [["7" "3" "1"]["2" "9"]] and I need to add zeros from the last element of each slice to the first one. For each step the counter of zeros is incremented by +1. Therefore, stdout is expected to be [["700", "30", "1"]["20", "9"]].

I have tried to do such an algorithm but can't get expected answer. Here is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func addZero(strs [][]string) [][]string {
    zero := "0"
    counter := 0
    for i := range strs {
        for j := range strs[i] {
            strs[i][j] += strings.Repeat(zero, counter)
        }
        counter++
    }
    return strs
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(addZero([][]string{{"7", "3", "1"}, {"2", "9"}}))// here the result is [[7 3 1] [20 90]]
 
}
```

How to change my code to get an expected answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counting zeros has to reset in each line, so move that code inside the first loop.

Also range goes from index `0`, and you want increasing zeroes from the end of lines, so `counter` has to start from `len(strs[i])-1`, and you have to decrement it:

```
func addZero(strs [][]string) [][]string {
    for i := range strs {
        zero := "0"
        counter := len(strs[i]) - 1
        for j := range strs[i] {
            strs[i][j] += strings.Repeat(zero, counter)
            counter--
        }
    }
    return strs
}
```

With these changes output will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/uYsGcgTXdkO)):

```
[[700 30 1] [20 9]]
```

Note that if you would process lines from the end, the suffix to append (the zeros) would increase. So you could ditch `strings.Repeat()` by keeping and "extending" the previous suffix:

```
func addZero(strs [][]string) [][]string {
    for _, line := range strs {
        zeros := ""
        for i := len(line) - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
            line[i] += zeros
            zeros += "0"
        }
    }
    return strs
}
```

This outputs the same. Try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/umPFaTVN7jD).

Also note that strings can be sliced, and the result shares the memory with the sliced string. So it's fast and does not create garbage! You could build a single, long `zeros` string holding just zeros, and you could slice this long string to have as many zeros as you need to append. This solution avoids any unnecessary string allocations and concatenations:

```
var zeros = strings.Repeat("0", 1000) // Use the maximum length here

func addZero(strs [][]string) [][]string {
    for _, line := range strs {
        count := len(line) - 1
        for i := range line {
            line[i] += zeros[:count-i]
        }
    }
    return strs
}
```

This again outputs the same, try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/7PAM95grXjI).